# PostgreSQL constraint error

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

i m having this error:

```
ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "vulling"
```

This is my code to make a foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE put_25_vlak_1_spoor
ADD FOREIGN KEY (spoor,vulling)
REFERENCES vulling(spoor,vulling);
```

The tables are made this way:

```
CREATE TABLE put_25_vlak_1_spoor
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  geometry_spoor geometry(MultiPolygon,28992),
  spoor integer NOT NULL,
  put integer,
  vlak integer,
  vulling integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT put_25_vlak_1_spoor_pkey PRIMARY KEY (spoor, vulling)
)

CREATE TABLE vulling
(
  vlak smallint,
  textuur character varying(8),
  vulling integer NOT NULL,
  spoor integer NOT NULL,
  put integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT vulling_pkey PRIMARY KEY (vulling, put, spoor)
)
```

I read this threads on stackoverflow but i don't fully understand what they are saying:

[PostgreSQL constraint problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902347/postgresql-constraint-problems)

[Postgresql constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005226/postgresql-constraint)

[What is causing ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966420/what-is-causing-error-there-is-no-unique-constraint-matching-given-keys-for-ref)

I hope somebody can help me out. Im very new to postgres and dont fully understand how the foreign keys work.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On (referenced) table `vulling` you need to have uniqe values for your foreign key. But you don't. You have unique values for triplet `(vulling, put, spoor)` which not nessecerly mean uniqness of pair `(spoor, vulling)`.

Consider

```
vulling
======================
vulling | put | spoor
----------------------
1       | 0   | 0
1       | 1   | 0
```

That two rows are uniqe in terms of triplet but not as a pair of `vulling` and `spoor`.
In the end you should either  add `UNIQUE(vulling, spoor)` to your table definition, or manage many-to-many relation using helper-table.

Alternatively you may reverse te foreign key def:

```
ALTER TABLE vulling
ADD FOREIGN KEY (spoor,vulling)
REFERENCES put_25_vlak_1_spoor(spoor,vulling);
```

Comment: i also though that and i search with this sql:

select spoor, vulling
from vulling
group by spoor,vulling
having count (*) > 1

and 

select spoor, vulling
from put_25_vlak_1_spoor
group by spoor,vulling
having count (*) > 1

but there were no double records. I have some double if i do only spoor. Maybe thats the problem?

Comment: It's not only about no-dublication it is about not **allowing** dublication to occure ever. You get that by defining unique constraint for pair of calumns.

Comment: i made both of the columns a primary keys. In that way there is no dublication(at least i thought so). If i make it unique the column, i cant do something like this: spoor =10 vulling =1 and spoor =10 and vulling = 2. But i want to do that in my database

Comment: Read my answer (i've edited it a little bit)  in table `vulling` you create triple primary key `(vulling, put, spoor)` that doesn't mean that `(spoor, vulling)` in that table is unique. But it must be in your case to define such a `foreign key` as you want. Or you may try to reverse the foreign key.

Comment: it works! thanks, but still have a problem. i removed the primary ket on put. But i want vulling also be connected to another table, i need the primary key also on put. I get a new error: ERROR: connot drop constraint vulling_pkey on tabel vulling because objects depend on it. Detail: constraint pu_25_vlak_1_spoor_spoor_fkey on table put _25_vlak_1_spoor depends on index vulling_pkey. HINT Use DROP...CASCADE to drop the depend object too

Comment: Now you have the same situation but in "the other side". Before you was not able to create foreign key because of wrong `PK`. Now you cannot delete `Primary Key` because it takes part in `FOREIGN KEY` (FK). First drop `foreign key` correct PK, and then recraete FK.

Comment: thanks you very much, i understand now how it works!

Answer (score 0):

Did you have data in the vulling table?
You can't add data to the put_25_vlak_1_spoor if in the vulling doesn't exist the same data in rows spoor,vulling.

i.e. if you want to add to the put_25_vlak_1_spoor a record, where spoor=111 and vulling=222, in the vulling have to be a row where spoor=111 and vulling=222

Comment: i checked it and there were indeed two records that existed in put25_vlak_1_spoor that didn;t exist in vulling. I added them to the table vulling. But i still have the same error.

ps. I got more records in vulling then put25_vlak_1_spoo